# Как найти все длинные слова в массиве?

Tags: массивы, ruby, length

Как изменить код, чтоб в массив сохранялся не только одно максимальное или минимальное значения массива, а несколько.  В этом коде в новый массив сохраняется только одно максимальное значения `"JavaScript"` а максимальных значений массиве два `"JavaScript","LiveScript"` Не судите строго я новичок.

```
x=["COBOL", "Ceylon", "Swift", "JavaScript", "R","LiveScript"]
s=[]
s=x.max { |a, b| a.length <=> b.length }
p s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = ["COBOL", "Ceylon", "Swift", "JavaScript", "R","LiveScript"]

vc = x.sort{|a,b| b.size <=> a.size}
vc.delete_if{|a| a.size < vc.first.size} 

p vc
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если мы добавим например в массив цифры, она их не удивить, как сделать что и цифры замечены были,  а что метод delete_if ?

Comment: @Явжизни, посмотрите разницу https://repl.it/talk/share/EnormousVirtualMedia/6594

Comment: выдает ошибку undefined method `x' for main:Object
(repl):3:in `<main>'

Comment: @Явжизни, https://repl.it/talk/share/EnormousVirtualMedia/6595

Comment: ["COBOL", "Ceylon", "Swift", "JavaScript", "R","LiveScript", 123456789] меня интересует может он заметить в массиве цифры и тоже их сохранить как длинное значения массива вместе строковыми данными.

Comment: @Явжизни, лично я пока не смог добиться такого результата, хотя много пробовал, если сделаю как-нибудь, отпишусь вам